# How do hide or not load the div based on the visibility of another div

Tags: angular

I want to not show the default-div if div-two is visible. I know I can just wrap default-div inside *ngIf="tokenValid" and it will work but its taking around 2 seconds for the response to come from the server and I don't want the default div to be hidden for those 2 seconds. So I would like to hide it if err-two div would be visible and it will only be visible if token is false.

```
<div class="default-div">
    Show this default block
    </div>

    <div class="err-two" *ngIf="!tokenValid">
    Sorry invalid
    </div>
```

Typescript

```
ngOnInit() {
    const token = {
      token: this.form.token
    }
    this.auth.resetPasswordToken(token).subscribe( (res: any) => {
      if(res) {
       this.tokenValid = true;
      }
    },(err)=> {
    if(err) {
      this.tokenValid = false;
    }
    });

  }
```

Comment: I want to reccomend you to do next steps: 1) add spiner, 2) add to first div *ngIf="tokenValid"

Comment: initialize tokenValid as `true`, have your default block with *ngIf="tokenValid"?

Comment: But I don't understand though, aren't both divs currently showing initially since tokenValid is false/undefined/null?

Answer (score 0):

Try this. `tokenValid = true` initially

```
<div *ngIf="tokenValid ; else invalid">
  default
</div>

<ng-template #invalid>
sorry invalid
</ng-template>
```